# get EWS identity token by VSTO plugin

Tags: c#, vsto, exchangewebservices

For the reason that our plugin need to listen always (so also in the background) to user interaction (read an email), where trying to rebuild an Outlook (Javascript) Add-in to a VSTO plugin.

Within the Javascript Add-In it's very easy to get the EWS Identity Token, but I can't find a way to achieve this within the C# VSTO plugin.
Do you have any suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you need the EWS identity token for? The Javascript add-in is different than the VSTO one. In VSTO you can make a SOAP request to the Exchange EWS to call a specific web method.

Or if your project is already using a web service than you can make the call to the Exchange  directly from there using the EWS managed API reference.

Comment: To make an EWS request from a VSTO adin, you need to provide the auth token, which is exactly what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way of doing that. The best you can do is patch the `WinHttpSendRequest` WinHTTP function using Detours, and spy on the `Authorization` and `X-User-Identity` HTTP headers on the outgoing requests.